# in barycentric coordinates why does $[PBC] = x[ABC]$?

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

From the Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads written by Even Chan, there is a chapter about barycentric coordinates. It is said in the chapter that

> Barycentric coordinates are also sometimes called areal coordinates because if $P = (x, y, z)$, then the signed area $[PBC]$ is equal to $x[ABC]$ and so on. In other words, these coordinates can be viewed as $$P = (\frac{[PBC]}{[ABC]}, \frac{[PCA]}{[BCA]}, \frac{[PAB]}{[CAB]})$$

I found [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) about this but it's a bit too technical for me to understand. Could anyone put it in a simpler way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us your own understanding/definition of barycentric coordinates?

Comment: In $\Delta ABC$, each point P can be assigned an ordered triple $(x, y, z)$ such that $\vec{P} = x\vec{A} + y\vec{B} + z\vec{C}$ and $x + y + z = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the barycentric area formula (listed in $p.120$ of Evan's book) which states that for $P_1, P_2, P_3$ be points with barycentric coordinates $P_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. Then,
$$\frac{[P_1P_2P_3]}{[ABC]} =\begin{vmatrix}x_1&y_1&z_1\\x_2&y_2&z_2\\x_3&y_3&z_3\end{vmatrix}$$
where $[PQR]$ denotes the signed area of $\Delta PQR$. We have

$$\frac{[PBC]}{[ABC]} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
P_1&P_2&P_3\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{vmatrix}=P_1$$

The same logic goes for $P_2, P_3$.